# Is it possible to use path slugs for API routes in Next.JS?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, app-router

I use app router of Next.js v.14 and have the following directories structure:

```
/app/api/github/webhook/[token]/route.ts
```

How can I get the `[token]` value inside the `POST` request handler? Are there dedicated fields in the `NextRequest` structure?

The official documentation completely missed the point of using `[slugs]` inside API routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official example [dynamic-route-segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#dynamic-route-segments).

You can access the token as below:

```
export const POST = async ( req, {params} ) => {
    console.log("token value ");
    console.log(params.token);
    const postData = await req.json();
    ...
}
```